# How fast can an iPhone register a tap on screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

I'm looking to create a game where it counts how fast a user can press a button on the screen in a small duration of time.

I'm having some problems as not all of my buttons are being registered. I'm not sure what the problem is, but could it be because of the iPhone emulator on xCode? or is there some time of limitation?

Comment: For something this sensitive to timing and hardware conditions, I wouldn't trust the emulator at all. Do some serious tests on an actual device before you invest too much time into any of this.

Comment: If you are using UIScrollViews those can for example delay touches

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly in the small ms range.  I've had to lock responding to touches out for some actions that took far less than a second to make it finish atomically before allowing the user to tap again.
The best you can probably do is take a timestamp first thing in the touchesbegan callback.